# Curl not working in Google App Engine Local on Windows, Works in Production

Tags: php, google-app-engine, curl

I'm not able to use `curl_lite` as I need certificate.  Curl works fine in production but not through the Google App Engine Dev server.

Here's my `php.ini`:

```
extension = "curl.so"
google_app_engine.enable_functions = "phpversion, phpinfo, php_sapi_name, php_uname, getmypid"
google_app_engine.allow_include_gs_buckets = "df_sabre_queue"
allow_url_include = 1
```

The error message thrown is:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function App\SomeClass\curl_init() in C:\Users\Egroeg\Code\SampleApp\app\Sabre\Request.php on line 52
```

`App.yaml` is:

```
application:    sample-app
version:        1
runtime:        php55
    api_version:    1

handlers:
    - url: /favicon\.ico
      static_files: public/favicon.ico
      upload: public/favicon\.ico

    - url: /.*
      script: public/index.php

skip_files:
    - ^(.*/)?#.*#$
    - ^(.*/)?.*~$
    - ^(.*/)?.*\.py[co]$
    - ^(.*/)?.*/RCS/.*$
    - ^(.*/)?\.(?!env).*$
    - ^(.*/)?node_modules.*$
    - ^(.*/)?_ide_helper\.php$
    - ^(.*/)?\.DS_Store$
```

`extension_loaded('curl')` returns false.

Comment: Is your dev environment windows? If so you'll need php_curl.dll instead of curl.so.

Comment: Well that was a simple solution to a very stupid problem.  Submit as answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your development environment is windows the extensions have slightly different names (to be consistent with the documentation you would find on php.net)

For windows, change the php.ini file to

```
extension = "php_curl.dll"
```

Not that in production we accept **either** `php_curl.dll` or `curl.so` to load the curl extension so you do not need to change the php.ini file before pushing your app.

Comment: Thanks.  I generally use a VM w/ Ubuntu for my dev box but the launcher was so easy to use I didn't bother.  Didn't think of this!

Comment: Any idea as to why is there no mention of this in the GAE documentation? I assumed `curl.so` should be used *everywhere* to not break GAE deployments.

Comment: Windows users are familiar with that format, and if you read any SO or other help website they will say use "php_curl.dll" - having it different on windows just for GAE would be more confusing I think.